# Store function Controller didnt get value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

im triying to save data with dynamic table in laravel.
If there isnt data, when im creating new one, the row successfully save.
but when im trying to add new row i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'description' cannot be null
```

i have declare the input element name on js as name="description", but still error.

This is my javascript:

```
<script src="{{ asset ('js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    var actions = $(".table-bawah td:last-child").html();
    // Append table with add row form on add new button click
    $(".add-new").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var index = $(".table-bawah tbody tr:last-child").index();
        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<form  id="aboutForm" action= {{route('quoteabout.store')}} method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">' +
            '@' + 'csrf' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description"></td>' +
            '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
            '</form>'
        '</tr>';
        $(".table-bawah").append(row);      
        $(".table-bawah tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
```

This is my table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered-bd-warning table-head-bg-warning table-bawah">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @forelse($dataAboutList as $index => $rowAboutList)
        <tr>
        <form id="aboutForm1" action="{{route('quoteabout.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart
/form-data">
        @csrf
            <td>{{ $rowAboutList->description }}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons" onclick="
document.getElementById('aboutForm1').submit()">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;
</i></a>
                <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#x
E872;</i></a>
            </td>
        </form>
        </tr>
        @empty
        <tr>
            <form id="aboutForm" action="{{route('quoteabout.store')}}" method="post" enctype="
multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" 
placeholder="Isi Judul" required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip" style="display: inline-block;" on
click="document.getElementById('aboutForm').submit()"><i class="material-icons">&#x
E03B;</i></a>
                <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip" style="display: none;"><i class="
material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#x
E872;</i></a>
            </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my Controller:

```
public function storeAboutList(Request $request)
    {
        Quote::create([
            'section'       => "About",
            'description'   => $request->description 
        ]);
    }
```

Edit:
i have update code in table from 
`onclick="document.getElementById('aboutForm1').submit()"` to
`onclick="document.getElementById('aboutForm').submit()"`

but action link cant get baseurl like below
[image]

Update, i change route in javascript and url already shown, but now i get error Page Expired.

Comment: is your request reaching to controller?

Comment: one more thing is, I just looked at your code, please don't use `aboutForm` id multiple times. it's not a standard practice.

Comment: Try checking `dd($request->description);` in your controller to know whether you are getting the value or not

Comment: JQuery is looking for the id `aboutForm` and will populate the data from the first id it finds. That's why your description is empty.

Comment: my request already reaching the controller, its fine. the id is different, i found my issue is when my table not empty i use aboutForm1 onclick, but im prepared aboutForm on javascript. After i change onclick to aboutForm, i got other error that js cant return the base url on action tag.

Comment: Your description is reading as empty. Do you have many form with same name or id of input? if that's the case it will read the first input with the same name or id.